# Check whether iPhone device connected with system from commandline?

Tags: iphone, usb

One of my requirement is "whether iPhone/iPad connected with system from command line" in my currently developing component. or any other systematic way rather than manual?

Expecting your favorable reply soon. thanks in advance...

sri

Comment: Which command line? Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: I need it for both OS (Linux and Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac:

```
ioreg -w -p IOUSB | grep -w iPad
ioreg -w -p IOUSB | grep -w iPhone
```

I don't know how an iPod Touch shows up.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. how about in windows? I am also looking in windows too...